# Processing JSON from a .txt file and converting to a DataFrame in Julia

Tags: json, julia, dataframes.jl

Cross posting from [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/processing-json-from-a-txt-file-and-converting-to-a-dataframe/61119) in case anyone here has any leads.

I’m just looking for some insight into why the below code is returning a dataframe containing just the first line of my json file. If you’d like to try working with the file I’m working with, you can download the aminer_papers_0.zip from the [Microsoft Open Academic Graph site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/open-academic-graph/), I’m using the first file in that group of files.

```
using JSON3, DataFrames, CSV
file_name = "path/aminer_papers_0.txt"
json_string = read(file_name, String)
js = JSON3.read(json_string)
df = DataFrame([js])
```

The resulting DataFrame has just one line, but the column titles are correct, as is the first line. To me the mystery is why the rest isn’t getting processed. I think I can rule out that read() is only reading the first JSON object, because I can index into the resulting object and see many JSON objects:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be4Lb.png)

My first guess was maybe the newline \n was causing escape issues, and tried to use chomp to get rid of them, but couldn’t get it to work.

Anyway - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you share the file you are processing? The whole zip would take 9h to download on my machine.

Comment: Yes - I will create a sharing link soon. The individual files are also quite big, though, so it will take a few minutes to put in a place I can share it from.

Comment: Okay - I think you should be able to get it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mfv8e7uc2267786/aminer_papers_0.txt?dl=0

Comment: OK - I see that the file has 9GB. Unfortunately I do not have enough RAM to process it. Maybe @quinnj will be able to have a look at your problem. I will ping him. Have you tried using https://github.com/JuliaData/JSONTables.jl?

Comment: OKay - no trouble. And I haven't given JSONTables a proper try, yet.

Comment: Just tried - and I think the deeper nesting of this JSON might be preventing it from working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the file is in [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format, and the JSON3 library only returns the first valid JSON value that it finds at the start of a string unless told otherwise.

## tl;dr

Call `JSON3.read` with the keyword argument `jsonlines=true`.

## Why?

By default, JSON3 interprets a string passed to its `read` function as a single "JSON text", defined by [RFC 8259 section 1.3.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-2):

> A JSON text is **a** serialized value....

(My emphasis on the use of the indefinite singular article "a.") A "JSON value" is defined in [section 1.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-3):

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of the following three literal names: false, null, true.

A string with multiple JSON values in it is technically multiple "JSON texts." It is up to the parser to determine what part of the string argument you give it is a JSON text, and the authors of JSON3 chose as the default behavior to parse from the start of the string to the end of the first valid JSON value.

In order to get JSON3 to read the string as multiple JSON values, you have to give it the keyword option `jsonlines=true`, which is documented as:

> `jsonlines`: A Bool indicating that the `json_str` contains newline delimited JSON strings, which will be read into a `JSON3.Array` of the JSON values. See [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org/) for reference. [default false]

## Example

Take for example this simple string:

```
two_values = "3.14\n2.72"
```

Each one of these lines is a valid JSON serialization of a number.  However, when passed to [`JSON3.read`](https://quinnj.github.io/JSON3.jl/stable/#JSON3.read), only the first is parsed:

```
using JSON3
@assert JSON3.read(two_values) == 3.14
```

Using `jsonlines=true`, both values are parsed and returned as a `JSON3.Array` struct:

```
@assert JSON3.read(two_values, jsonlines=true) == [3.14, 2.72]
```

## Other Packages

The [JSON.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/JSON.jl) library, which people might use by default given the name, does not implement parsing of JSON Lines strings at all, leaving it up to the caller to properly split the string as needed:

```
using JSON
JSON.parse(two_values)
# ERROR: Expected end of input
# Line: 1
# Around: ...3.14 2.72...
#                 ^
```

A simple way to implement reading multiple values is to use [`eachline`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.eachline):

```
@assert [JSON.parse(line) for line in eachline(IOBuffer(two_values))] == [3.14, 2.72]
```

Comment: I think you have to be careful about using `eachline`, as it will split JSON strings that contain newlines themselves, such as `{"a": "new\nline"}`. To avoid this, you'd have to write your own JSON parser... easier to just use JSON3.

Comment: Great catch! Except technically a string value with an unescaped control character, like \n, is invalid JSON by [section 7 of RFC 8259](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-7), so that example should fail when parsed by a JSON parser that conforms to the standard. I checked, and JSON3 will not accept such a string as a value.

Comment: To clarify, if the code sequence U+000A (line feed) appears in a string value, then that is an invalid JSON string. However, line feeds can appear outside string values in valid JSON (they are considered whitespace and ignored), and the `eachline` method above _will_ fail when reading text formatted like that. Like BallpointBen says, it's better to just use a parser like `JSON3` that correctly handles the JSON Lines format.